# Using Overdot in function Module?

Tags: front-end, formatting

Fundamental problem is: Is there any way I can use OverDot[var] as symbol in a function? I have tried to use `Symbolize[OverDot[x,1]]` for example, to no avail.

If I try I get the following error:

[image: Error because OverDot[x] is not a symbol]

It does of course work to make all the dotted variables into just {xdot, ydot, zdot}:

```
getVelocitySphericalFromCartesian[v_, vdot_] :=

 Module[{x, y, z, xdot, ydot, zdot, rdot, \[Theta]dot, \[Phi]dot},
  {x, y, z} = v;
  {xdot, ydot, zdot} = vdot;
  {x,y,z,xdot,ydot,zdot} (*Some function of these six variables here*)
]
```

But I'm interested in making it look better and prettier by using the dots. Is it possible?

Comment: You could try using `\[FormalX]`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Notation`AutoLoadNotationPalette = False;(*prevents Notation palette from popping up*)
(* or allow the pallete to pop up *)
<< Notation`
```

Replace `...` with typeset form of `OverDot[x]`:

```
Module[{ ... = 2},  ...]

Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[OverscriptBox[_, "."]]];

Module[{ ... = 2},  ...]
```

> ```
> Module[{ ... = 2},  ...]
> ```
>
> 2

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked!
By the way, how did you know that it was OverscriptBox? If I put x then Ctrl+&, period, into FullForm it said OverDot[x,1], however the warning said it was Overscript, and finally, you give used OverscriptBox? Can you explain the command a little if you have time? In any case, thanks again!

Comment: A little off-topic: is there any way to make the dots render a little bigger btw?

Comment: @GandalfSaxe The front end converts to box structures for display. Try `MakeBoxes[OverDot[x], StandardForm]` to see the form the front end works with.

Comment: @GandalfSaxe You could always do `Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[OverscriptBox["x", "\[FilledSmallCircle]"]]]` or `Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[OverscriptBox["x", "\[FilledCircle]"]]]` and then copy the output of `Overscript[x, \[FilledSmallCircle]]` or `Overscript[x, \[FilledCircle]]` respecitvely. You could also control the size of `"."` with `Style` / `StyleBox`.